# Ways to redirect email server users safely

Tags: security, node.js, email, smtp

I am building a nodeJS based email server (homework assignment). I need to find a way to safely redirect users to their page after validating info. Right now I just response with a URL as follows `/mail.html?user=username`

This is obviously wrong - any use of GET/POST parameters is easily hacked.
I think that any further request the user makes (checking inbox, sent mail for example) will have to be verified by his password again.

Am I right? Is there a common method to solve my problem?

Thanks

P.s I can't use external nodeJS modules

Answer (score 1):

You need to be verifying credentials server-side for **every** request.

Each request should have the username/password or some sort of session token included with it.  Also beware of sending user credentials in plaint-text over the wire.  Use HTTPS.